# Trying to get awk o/p assigned to variable inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Need help with awk
 Trying to get awk o/p assigned to variable; getting following error.

```
var=  $(awk '{print $2;next;}' <<< "$OLD_ADDR")
        echo $var    

Where ...OLD_ADDR = "gateway 192.168.1.1"


 ******** Error from console log using set -x *******

    +++ awk '{print $2;next;}'
    ++ var=
    ++ 192.168.1.21
    -bash: 192.168.1.21: command not found
    ++ echo
```

Thank you,
pisignage@ariemtech.com

Answer (score 1):

*Spaces matter.*

Consider:

```
var=  $(awk '{print $2;next;}' <<< "$OLD_ADDR")
```

This tells the shell to set the variable `var` to empty and then run whatever command the `awk` statement prints out.  In your case, that command is  `192.168.1.1`.  Since the shell can find no such command on the PATH, the error is generated:

```
-bash: 192.168.1.21: command not found
```

The solution is to write:

```
var=$(awk '{print $2;next;}' <<< "$OLD_ADDR")
```

This will, by contrast, assign the output of the `awk` command to `var`.

When making an assignment in shell, no spaces are allowed on either side of the equal sign.